# Is it possible to run an embedded resource as an administrator?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, embedded-resource, administrator

I have an embedded resource that I am trying to integrate into my program and in order for the embedded resource to run, it needs to be run as an administrator. How can this be done?

My code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FilePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\npcli.exe"

    Using MsiFile As New FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create)
        MsiFile.Write(My.Resource.npcli, 0, My.Resource.npcli.Length)
    End Using

    Dim x As String = "/driver /add 192.168.1.1 /port 1 /com 4"

    Process.Start(FilePath, x)
End Sub
```

I am not receiving an error when I try and run my program, it just does not run the embedded resource correctly because it needs to be run as an administrator. I also tried to open Visual Studio as an administrator, and that does not fix the issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Double check you have UAC enabled.I ran into this issue at a prior company. You need to make sure you get the elevation dialog for you to hit yes when you run VS as an admin. Otherwise, you may not really be running as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a process with administrator privileges you set the process's [**`StartInfo.Verb`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verb(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `runas`:

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(FilePath, x)
psi.Verb = "runas"

Process.Start(psi)
```